# Angular $http get parameters conversion

Tags: json, angularjs

When I have this kind of object:

```
myObj = {
    accountNumber:"12345",
    limit:"10",
    offset:"0",
    serviceProduced: {
        min:"2015-03-01"
    }
}
```

and I pass it via $http get as params:

```
$http({
    url: '/foo'
    method: 'GET'
    params: myObj
});
```

for some reason it comes to server like this after its JSONified by `$http`:

```
{"accountNumber":"1191009461","limit":"10","offset":"0","serviceProduced":"{\"min\":\"2015-03-01\"}"}
```

How can I prevent the 'serviceProduced' not to be converted to string? So that it would be like this (correct):

```
{"accountNumber":"1191009461","limit":"10","offset":"0","serviceProduced":{"min":"2015-03-01"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are miss using http get. It is not supposed to support nested objects.
It should be in the following format: `?accountNumber=1191009461&limit=10&...`

However, if you want to achieve what you are looking for, you can configure your object to be like:

```
myObj = {
    accountNumber:"12345",
    limit:"10",
    offset:"0",
    "serviceProduced.min": "2015-03-01", // you should be able to handle this format server side.
    // OR
    "serviceProduced[min]": "2015-03-01"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$http.get("#{url}", myObj)...
```

it should work.